# Magento display multiple breadcrumbs in product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, breadcrumbs

In my site I need to show all (Display Full Breadcrumb Path) category and sub category in breadcrumbs.

My product in many category like this :

```
Shirts >> full sleeves >> product A
T-Shirts >> Polo >> product A
Sweaters >> Woolen >> product A
Men >> Dresses >> product A
```

Like above I want to **display all in breadcrumb [all categories which the product belongs to]** in next next lines.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I did the extension in below GitHub Url with below feature :

https://github.com/vijays91/Magento-Advanced-Breadcrumbs

- Display the full path in product breadcrumbs (show all category
  paths).
- To display the single and multiple category breadcrumbs in product
  view page.
- Helps this module, search engines to parse your breadcrumbs (Home / Search result for: 'XXX' / XXX).
- Breadcrumbs are added to customer account pages.
- Added breadcrumbs to contact us page.

Comment: single link answers are not the best answers. Try to add a few words about how your extension works.

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer @Marius

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to modify `page/html/breadcrumb.phtml` checking if you are in a product's page and then change your breadcrumb behaviour.

Something like this:

```
<?php if ($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')): ?>
    <?php
    $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($cats as $catId): ?>
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <ul>

                <?php $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); ?>
                <?php
                $parentPath = explode('/', $_cat->getPath());
                $parentPath = array_splice($parentPath, 2);
                ?>
                <?php foreach ($parentPath as $parentId): ?>
                    <?php $_prentCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId); ?>
                    <li><?php echo $_prentCat->getName() ?></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <li><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else: ?>
    ... // Standard breadcrumb code
<?php endif; ?>
```

For best performance use this:

```
<?php if ($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')): ?>
    <?php $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($cats as $catId): ?>
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <ul>

                    <?php $parentPath = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getAttributeRawValue($catId, 'path'); ?>
                    <?php
                    $parentPath = explode('/', $parentPath);
                    $parentPath = array_splice($parentPath, 2);
                    ?>
                    <?php foreach ($parentPath as $parentId): ?>
                        <li><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getAttributeRawValue($parentId, 'name')) ?></li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    <li><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
... // Standard breadcrumb code
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this does not give you the full category tree path. It only gives you the categories directly linked to the products. In the example the OP offered you will only get `full sleeves`, `Polo`, `Woolen`, `Dresses`.   not to mention that calling load in a loop in a template is very bad for performance and for code aesthetics

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can use $_cat->getPath() to get the category parents.

Comment: I modified my original answer to include the parent categories, check it now.

Comment: Now you have a load in 2 loops. It is even worse

Comment: @Marius, they are different categories. To optimize it we should get all the ids and retrieve a collection. Do you have better options?

Comment: You could try that. You can even try multiple collections. One for each category branch. It is still better than a load

Comment: What if we just use Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category') ->getAttributeRawValue() ?

Comment: I changed it to use raw data access, it should be faster than category load